# Can't sftp into server Permission denied, please try again

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp

While trying to SFTP in to my server i get

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Even though i am using the right password.

SSHD_CONFIG for server im trying to connect to.

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 25595
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication no
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -l INFO

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Full sftp -v -v -v -p HostImConnectingto 25595 output

```
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "HostImConnectingto" from file "/home/grayson/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/grayson/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "24.231.182.21" from file "/home/grayson/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/grayson/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'HostImConnectingto' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/grayson/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/grayson/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
grayson@static.deepdreamconverter.net's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 64 padlen 16 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
grayson@HostImConnectingto password:
```

I can putty into the box fine, but when i try ssh -p 25595 user@WhereImTryingToConnect from another box it does not work. both boxes are ubuntu 14.04

EDIT 1: i have changed PasswordAuthentication from no to yes, and restarted the ssh service. but when i try sftp -v -v -v -p grayson@static.MYSITE.net 25595. i am still getting the error

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
```

i have tried 2 different users, and i can verify both passwords have been put in correctly

EDIT 2: i have gotten ssh from box b (computer trying to connect) and box a (computer im connecting to)
first i gened a key on box b.
then tried to copy the key to box a, got an error saying

```
bash: line 2: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
```

so my first thought was okay permissions on box a are messed up. (even though ive set them to 700 and 600 respectively )
I then went and set ~/.ssh to 777 (THIS IS BAD DO NOT DO) and i also set ~/.ssh/ to 777 (ALSO BAD). with this i was able to copy my ssh key from box b to box a. I am now also able to remote in to box A from B. but i can still not SFTP into box a from b...

Comment: You need to look at your SERVER logs to see why the server is denying access. The client log isn't very helpful.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq currently i am trying to look for the system log that has the reason.. but from what i found it should be in the auth log.. but i can not find the auth log in /etc/log..

Comment: Logs are in /var/log not /etc/log

Comment: @qasdfdsaq oops i ment /var/log.. currently auth.log is not there :(

Comment: Then you need to add the appropriate logging directives into your sshd_config (SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO)

Comment: @qasdfdsaq i have added Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -l verbose to my sshd_config, but still nothing in my auth.log..

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as on askubuntu:

You need to set `PasswordAuthentication yes` instead of `PasswordAuthentication no` in your `sshd_config`.

Comment: i have changed the config to PasswordAuthentication yes, but still no luck..

Comment: Did you restart SSH after you made the change? Ex. `sudo service sshd restart`

Comment: in my variant in /etc/ssh/sshd_config already did exist tunning PasswordAuthentication Yes and did return error Permission denied, please try again.